# org.json.JSONException: No value for status Android Parsing

Tags: java, android, json

Hello i have an error in my code in json parsing where the error is

> org.json.JSONException: No value for status

```
JSONObject c = new JSONObject();

try {

    if(c.has("status")) {
```

This is the Json format, i have problem in getting status value.

```
{
    "id": "7",
    "nome": "dfsdfsdfsdff",
    "email": "and@gmail.com",
    "status": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to put your response in JSONObject constructor

```
JSONObject c = new JSONObject(yourResponseString);
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Currently it is empty hence no status or anything else

Comment: post your complete code and also make sure your response string is not null , verify it using log

Comment: Your json string maybe null